# How can I automatically generate numbers for headings for right to left language in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice, rtl

I write arabic, in libreoffice how can I write a heading and libreoffice  automatically generates that numbers for example:

```
      first chapter (1   
     second chapter (2  
  section one (1-2  
  section two (2-2  
 section three(3-2
```

Note that when I write in english it is easy and I can do that, but for right to left languages that does not work correctly and I can only produce below numbering which is false:

```
        first chapter (1 
       secend chapter (2
  section one (2-1
  section two (2-2
 section three(2-3
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This seems to be a bug with i18n/RTL support that should be reported up stream against liberoffice. https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/